# Add a margin to li using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using `flexbox` to layout my things. I have 5 `lis` (so far, but that will change), with the following width: `flex-basis:calc(100%/3)`. So there will be 3 `li's` in each row. The wrapper (`ul`) has a `width` of `70%`.

So far so good. The problem is, when I add a margin to the `li's`. When I add a `margin` to the `li's`, there will only be 2 `li's` in each row with some extra space, but I need 3.

So I found 2 solutions that give me other problems:

- One solution would be to add the margin to the `li's`, let's say `10px`. Then subtract `20px` (10 * 2) from the `width` and `height` of each `li's`. I can't do that, because I need the `li's` to be the size I set, and not smaller.
- Another solution would be to set `justify-content` to either `space-around` or `space-between`. The problem with that is that I need the `lis` to be in columns and rows, (like a chart). And if I change `justify-content`, the `li's` wouldn't be in a chart like order.

Is there a way to add a margin to the `li` without affecting any other property's?

(I'm open to `JavaScript/JQuery` if that's the only choice.)

#### JSFiddle

Here's a code snippet:

```css
body, html {
    height:100%; margin: 0; padding:0;
}
#flexWrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
#flexContainer {
    width: 70%;
    background-color:yellow;
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
 
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 align-items: center;
 align-content:flex-start;
}
li {
    background-color: tomato; border: 1px solid black; height:50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-basis:calc(100%/3);
    margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexWrapper">
    <ul id="flexContainer">
        <li class="flex-item">1</li>
        <li class="flex-item">2</li>
        <li class="flex-item">3</li>
        <li class="flex-item">4</li>
        <li class="flex-item">5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: how about calc(100% / 3 - 20px) , 20px is the total margin.

Comment: That works, but the aspect ratio of the `li's` change

Comment: If you're setting the `flex-basis` of each `li` to 33.33%, and you want three in a row, then you only have .01% left over for margin. Can you make the `li` 30%? Then you can apply a 2.5% margin. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/sfr0foxL/1/

Comment: Maybe it's possible to add to the width of `#flexContainer` (width: 70%), then add the remaining width to the `li's`? For example, we'll make the `#flexContainer` width to `79%`, and add another `3%` to all `li's`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Each of your `li`s is 33.33%. Three in a row equal (essentially) 100%. The 100% is the width of the container, whether it's 70% or 79%. The structure won't change if you increase the container width to 79%. But the li's will be wider.

Comment: So in addition to my last comment, we can subtract the `li's` percentage (`flex-basis:calc(100%/3 - 3%`) then add a `margin` of `1.5%`.

Comment: If you must keep the li's at 33.33%, then you really only have two options: Use borders and/or padding for separation. In this demo, each li has a 5px border matching the color of the background: http://jsfiddle.net/sfr0foxL/2/

Comment: Do you think I should use my trick? The size will stay the same **visually**.

Comment: If it works for you and you think it's stable and reliable, then why not. Give it a shot.

Comment: k. Lemme try. I'll post it as an answer if it works

Comment: I finally got a working answer! Just posted it. Let me know if you like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got an answer that works! I have to give partial credit to @Syahrul for starting up the idea (in the comments).

So basically what I'll be doing is this. If we want to add 1.5% of a margin, we'll add (1.5 * 2) * 3 (`1.5 * 2` because the margin is on both sides of every `li`. `* 3 because we have 3`li's`in every row.) to the`width`of the wrapper ('#flexContainer`), so we have `79%` of a width for `#flexContainer`.

Next, we'll subtract `3%` (margin size (1.5 * 2)) from the `width` of the `li`. And that's `flex-basis:calc(100%/3 - 3%)`.

And there you have it! Here's the updated [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sfr0foxL/3/)

```css
body, html {
    height:100%; margin: 0; padding:0;
}
#flexWrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
#flexContainer {
    width: 79%;
    background-color:yellow;
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
 
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 align-items: center;
 align-content:flex-start;
}
li {
    background-color: tomato; border: 1px solid black; height:100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-basis:calc(100%/3 - 3%);
    margin:1.5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexWrapper">
    <ul id="flexContainer">
        <li class="flex-item">1</li>
        <li class="flex-item">2</li>
        <li class="flex-item">3</li>
        <li class="flex-item">4</li>
        <li class="flex-item">5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```